# python request iugu return status 400

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, python-requests

I'm testing the api [iugu.com](http://iugu.com) to generate ticket payments and I'm in trouble on return of information in the post because there is error dictionary items that are sent to the api (in php would be an array)

the code is this:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, jsonify
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    dados = {
        'method':'bank_slip',
        'email':'cliente@exemplo.com',
        'items[]':[
            {'description':'Item Um', 'quantity':1, 'price_cents': 100000},
            {'description':'Item Dois', 'quantity':1, 'price_cents': 200000}
        ]
    } 

    url = 'https://api.iugu.com/v1/charge' 
    user = '002f38a6d40b0275fc08aaac503a775b'
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

    r = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, ''), headers = headers, params = json.dumps(dados))

    return jsonify(
        resposta = [
            r.json(),
            {
                'status': r.status_code,
                'cabecalho': r.headers['Content-Type'],
                'params': dados,
                'text': r.content,
                'url': r.url
            }
        ])

app.debug = True
app.use_reloader=True
app.run()
```

The answer:

```
{
  "resposta": [
    {
      "errors": "token n\u00e3o \u00e9 v\u00e1lido"
    }, 
    {
      "cabecalho": "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
      "params": {
        "email": "cliente@exemplo.com", 
        "items[]": [
          {
            "description": "Item Um", 
            "price_cents": 100000, 
            "quantity": 1
          }, 
          {
            "description": "Item Dois", 
            "price_cents": 200000, 
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ], 
        "method": "bank_slip"
      }, 
      "status": 400, 
      "text": "{\"errors\":\"token n\\u00e3o \\u00e9 v\\u00e1lido\"}", 
      "url": "https://api.iugu.com/v1/charge?%7B%22email%22:%20%22cliente@exemplo.com%22,%20%22items[]%22:%20[%7B%22price_cents%22:%20100000,%20%22description%22:%20%22Item%20Um%22,%20%22quantity%22:%201%7D,%20%7B%22price_cents%22:%20200000,%20%22description%22:%20%22Item%20Dois%22,%20%22quantity%22:%201%7D],%20%22method%22:%20%22bank_slip%22,%20%22format%22:%20%22json%22%7D"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you use as in the example of the site that looks like this:

```
'items[][description]':'Item Um', 
'items[][quantity]':'1', 
'items[][price_cents]':'100000',
```

The answer is correct but can not add more than one item because it only ranks second.
There is another way to send data or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Based on the error message: "token não é válido" I would say that you're not generating the token properly: https://iugu.com/referencias/api#tokens-e-cobranca-direta

Comment: The token is correct. The Api return it because of error in items. If it does happen the status-code 400 is the return status-code 200

Comment: Can you try naming the variable "items" instead of "items[]"?  I think the documentation is referring to it as "items[]" to demonstrate the fact that it's a list.  (But that may be because I can't read portuguese :)).

Comment: I tried it too and the error continues

Answer (score 0):

Received a tip the staff of **[iugu.com](http://iugu.com)** own to check the data that is sent via curl, is the **[postcatcher.in](http://postcatcher.in)**. There it was possible to create a session and direct the url of my application to the url that is in the browser after you start this site. This makes it possible to follow in real time the body tab, if the data was sent or not among other observations cabeçarios among other information (found it very cool)

With this site I saw it was not sent or items or anything you want it to be and it helped me to see that the the line of the requests was wrong.

Instead of using **params** was to use the right **data**.

Everything worked.